# Python Tkinter --AttributeError

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Cannot seem to figure out the below Tkinter message. Usually doing a quick
search will provide answers but this time I seem to miffed the search engines as to
what might be causing the below error.  Curious to know if I am missing a Python package or line 25 below is used in an older version of Python and it has been updated to
a newer command.

I am importing the following packages into the script:

**from tkinter import ***  
**from tkinter import filedialog**

The function is suppose to save any typed text put into a text area.  It does save the file but the file is empty.

Thanks,

Kurt

C:\Users\kurt>python --version
Python 3.10.4

---

```
def saveFiles():  
    filename = filedialog.asksaveasfile(
        mode='w',
        title="Save a File",
        defaultextension=".txt"
        )
    filename.config(mode='w')  ------------> **This is line 25**

    pathh.insert(END, filename)
    data = str(txtarea.get(1.0, END))
    filename.write(data)
    filename.close()


Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.1264.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1921, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "c:\Users\kurt\Documents\Scripts\TKinter\fileExplorerReadFile.py", line 25, in saveFiles
    filename.config(mode='w')
AttributeError: '_io.TextIOWrapper' object has no attribute 'config'
```

Comment: The error obviously tells you that `filename` (an instance of `_io.TextIOWrapper`) does not have `config()` function.  The `mode` has already been specified in `.asksaveasfile()`, so what do want to do on the problem line actually?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. The error told you that the code `filename.config(mode='w')` had a problem, yes? In your own words, what do you expect this code to do? Why? What do you expect `filename` to be at this point in the code? Did you check that? Why should it make sense to use `.config` with this value? What should it do?

Comment: "But this time I seem to miffed the search engines as to what might be causing the below error." What things did you try putting into the search? Also, what did you understand from the error message? For example, do you know what a `'_io.TextIOWrapper' object` is? If not, did you try looking that up separately? How about `AttributeError`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is saying that the object returned by the `asksaveasfile` method doesn't have a `config` method.

> `tkinter.filedialog.asksaveasfile(mode='w', **options)`¶
> Create a SaveAs dialog and return a file object opened in write-only mode.

When you call the `asksaveasfile` method, it automatically returns a file object in **write mode** already so there is no need for any further configuration to write to the file.  If you were to omit the line throwing the error, your code should work the way you intended.